# Auto Refresh WinForms DataGridView from Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I want to make a DataGridView in WinForms that pulls data from a database query. It should re-run the query every 10 seconds and auto refresh the DataGridView. The initial load and display of the data works fine. But after that every time I update (using a timer), I get the DataError `Index 0 has no value` three times and the selected cell becomes empty. Once the update is compelted (after 3-4 seconds), all cells are displayed correctly.

Running the update (including initial load):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => UpdateMatchesTable(dataGridView1));
}
```

Then the update method:

```
private void UpdateMatchesTable(DataGridView view)
{
    if (checkBoxAutoRefresh.Checked)
    {
        pendingMatchesTableAdapter.Fill(userObjectsDataSet.PendingMatches);
        view.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            (view.DataSource as BindingSource).ResetBindings(false);
        }));
    }
}
```

I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong here. Is this the right approach at all?

Comment: It sounds like you have some code on another event or events of the grid that fires in between the data refresh.

Comment: If you want to refresh the data from database in real time, I recommend to use [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency), instead of "timer".

Comment: Seems like the SQL server service broker is turned off in the database. So I can't use SqlDependency :/